# Optional short answer view for questions with many answers

Tags: feature-request, usability, optimization

In order to get an overview of the answers to a question, as a reader of "Best Practises", I want an option to see only the first line of every answer with a link to it.

Currently I read the answers sequentially. But when I want to go back to one answer I have to search all subpages until I find it.

This happened to me when I read [What are Code Smells? What is the best way to correct them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a search of `inquestion:this` when viewing the question, or you can supply the question number if you want to access from anywhere. For the example you gave (and this is going to be a link), [`inquestion:114342`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A114342) works.

This presents you with a list of all the answers with the same kind of excerpt fashion used on the questions list - basically just the first sentence for most of them. If you need to, you can throw in additional search parameters to filter through the answers.

Comment: Neat - but instead of being a hidden feature, it deserves to be a standard feature turned on if the no. of answers or total line length of answers exceeds some threshold.